# What's the difference between these two codes, so why am I getting an error?

Tags: java, spring

1.

```
    @RequestMapping("/")

    public @ResponseBody List<TestVo> query() throws Exception{

    return testService.getAll();
```

This code is The output is normal but

2.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/",produces="text/plain;charset=UTF-8")

    public @ResponseBody List<TestVo> query() throws Exception{

    return testService.getAll();
```

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No converter for [class java.util.ArrayList] with preset Content-Type 'null'

Why do I get an error?

Comment: Can you please share the headers your client is sending to the server?

Comment: What is the expected format of the response body, JSON ?

Comment: For those kinds of issues, you should post not only code examples, but also http requests examples. curl command example is the easiest way for that I suppose

Answer (score 3):

In the second case, you tell Spring to convert the ArrayList to a plain text (that's the difference). Since the library doesn't find the converter mapping array lists to plain text, it throws an exception.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Certainly, but an example of what? Your own code is a pretty good example of the behavior: you have a `produces="text/plain"` attribute. This causes Spring to look for an array to plain text converter and this fails, because no such converter is available (there's just a default converter to json and possibly xml).